# How to add locks to read and write from file methods

Tags: java, file-io, locks

I have to add locks to my readFromFile() and writeToFile() methods for school. Please see the method code below and advise me where in the code I would place the locks? Would I use ReentrantLock or ReadWriteReentrantLock? We have to use locks.

Thank you.

**Read method**

```
public static void readFromFile(List<Person> people)
{
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("names");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
     String name = sc.nextLine();
     int age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     people.add(new Person(name, age));
   }
   sc.close();
}
```

**Write method**

```
public static void writeToFile(List<Person> people)
{
  File outputFile = new File (List<Person> people)
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

  for (Person p: people) {
    pw.println(p.name); }

  pw.close();

}
```

Comment: probably easiest to synchronize on an Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guard whole method body

```
 static ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

  public static void readFromFile(List<Person> people) {
    rwl.readLock().lock();
    try {
...
      //method body is not changed
    } finally {
      rwl.readLock().unlock();
    }

  }

  public static void writeToFile(List<Person> people) {
    rwl.writeLock().lock();
    try {
...
      //method body is not changed
    } finally {
      rwl.writeLock().unlock();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock is a more fine granular control on the throughput.

A ReentrantLock has the same power as the java monitor locking with synchronized. It is just technically different.

If you have **many reads** and less writes it is worth to use a ReadWrite lock, because it allowes **reads in parallel** as long as there is **no write**.

If you use ReentrantLocks, always follow the **try-finally pattern** to have the lock free in any case. That is not needed with synchronized.

here a suggestion for the read in your example with readWrite. The write method is the same just use the writeLock().

```
private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new readWriteLock;

public static void readFromFile(List<Person> people) {
  readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
  try {
     // method body
  } finally {
     readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
  }
}
```